# Problem with sql connection string syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlclient

I'm trying to connect to SQL server using SQLCLIENT.

And I think I have a problem with CONNECTION STRING.

The name of the SERVER as it appears: "LAPTOP-LUC355KE \ MSSQLSERVER01"

When I write the name, C# has a problem with the "\", I tried to make "/" but I can't connect to the server and I get an error message that the name may not be correct.

> error: The network name cannot be found.

[image: C# code]

Comment: its c# you need to escape the \, put in 2 of them, or put an @ before the  beginning "

Comment: Please [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences) about escape codes in C# strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1 :** Use `@` at beginning of string

```
@"LAPTOP-LUC355KE \ MSSQLSERVER01"
```

**Method 2 :** Use the `Web.config` and its good practice to read the connection string from there

You need to add a reference to `System.Configuration` and then use:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["connectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\` character in machine name by doubling it.

This should get you started:

`LAPTOP-LUC355KE\\MSSQLSERVER01`

P.S.: Unless it is throw-away code you are writing, it is extremely bad practice to hard-code connection strings in the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Connection string:**

Bellow System.webserver

```
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="YourConection_String_Name"
      connectionString="Data Source= Your_Sql_Port_No; Initial Catalog=Your_Data_Base_Name;User ID=your_Sql_ID;Password=Your_Sql_Password;Max Pool Size=10240;Pooling=true;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

May It helps..